# Run local rake task on remote application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, rake

I'd like to be able to create and run local rake tasks on a application running on a remote server. My basic use case is as follows: I need to be able to quickly create various tasks for monitoring the database of the application without having to go through my various deploy steps. The ideal scenario for me would be to easily create rake tasks on my local machine, and run them at whatever interval I want on my live application.

Is this at all possible, and if not, is there any other way to accomplish something similar?

To clarify: this is only for the purpose of monitoring, not to change any live data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/seattlerb/rake-remote_task. Here is a snippet to show you how it works:

```
require 'rake/remote_task'
set :domain, 'abc.example.com'

remote_task :foo do
  run "ls"
end
```